# Working out closed form of shifted poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian, poisson-distribution

In the article "Bayesian variable selection for Poisson regression with
underreported responses" the author defines $t_i^0$ as the number of actual occurences in a study in the $i$th covariate pattern. Let $\lambda_i$ be the 
actual estimated rate of events, $\pi_i$ the probability of underreporting, $y_i$ the actual reported events, then the author assumes for $t_i^0$:

\begin{gather}
t_i^0 \text{~ shifted Poisson}(\lambda_i (1-\pi_i), y_i), \text{  where } t_i^0 = y_i, y_i+1,y_i+2, \ldots
\end{gather}

I was trying to work out a closed form for this equation like:

\begin{gather}
\displaystyle\frac{(\lambda_i(1-\pi_i))^{t_i^0}}{t_i^0!e^{\lambda_i(1-\pi_i)}}, 
\end{gather}

but when I use this formula to work out the Bayesian likelihood, I don't find the correct answer. Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?